# HTML5 Matterjs Canvas enable swiping on mobile

Tags: javascript, canvas, scroll, matter.js

I have created a simple canvas with MatterJs, with a bouncing and draggable ball.

Everything works fine on desktop; on mobile, i'd like to be able to swipe and scroll the page when i swipe on the canvas BUT drag the ball if I swipe on the ball (dragging it).

I can detect if the touch event is inside the ball or not, but can't figure out how to allow swiping on the canvas. Swiping on the whole canvas is also ok, allowing drag on mobile as well is secondary and not really important.